# distcp not working on CD4.5

Tags: cloudera

I upgraded from CDH 4.4.0-1.cdh4.4.0.p0.39 to CDH 4.5.0-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.30.  I had distcp working in prior version from hdfs to s3:

```
hadoop distcp -i -update -p hdfs://NN:8020/path/to/directory/folder/ s3n://accesskeyid:keypass@mybucket/directory/;
```

when upgrade I'm getting a few weird errors and warnings now:

```
WARN httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream: Attempting to release HttpMethod in finalize() as its response data stream has gone out of scope. This attempt will not always succeed and cannot be relied upon! Please ensure response data streams are always fully consumed or closed to avoid HTTP connection starvation.
```

13/12/10 11:26:27 WARN httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream: Successfully released HttpMethod in finalize(). You were lucky this time... Please ensure response data streams are always fully consumed or closed.

And errors:

```
    Task attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: 2013-12-10 10:52:32
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.6-b01 mixed mode):
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.PeerCache@4ed9f47" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96ccc8c000 nid=0x2801 waiting on condition [0x00007f96c2f0e000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.PeerCache.run(PeerCache.java:252)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.PeerCache.access$000(PeerCache.java:39)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.PeerCache$1.run(PeerCache.java:135)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "communication thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96ccc87800 nid=0x27f4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f96c327f000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - waiting on <0x00000000fcb34ee0> (a java.lang.Object)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$TaskReporter.run(Task.java:662)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - locked <0x00000000fcb34ee0> (a java.lang.Object)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "Timer thread for monitoring jvm" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96ccc57800 nid=0x27ed in Object.wait() [0x00007f96c3110000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - waiting on <0x00000000fcad8078> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - locked <0x00000000fcad8078> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cca80800 nid=0x27e4 waiting on condition [0x00007f96c33b5000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fcae0080> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:424)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:323)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:874)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:945)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "IPC Client (1065524847) connection to /127.0.0.1:38248 from job_201312042223_7900" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cca98800 nid=0x27e3 in Object.wait() [0x00007f96c34b6000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - waiting on <0x00000000fcac0188> (a org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.waitForWork(Client.java:803)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - locked <0x00000000fcac0188> (a org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:846)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "Thread for syncLogs" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cca5c800 nid=0x27e2 waiting on condition [0x00007f96c36bf000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$3.run(Child.java:156)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc0be000 nid=0x27dc runnable [0x0000000000000000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc0bb800 nid=0x27db waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc0b9000 nid=0x27da waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc0b6800 nid=0x27d9 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc09a000 nid=0x27d8 in Object.wait() [0x00007f96c89f8000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - waiting on <0x00000000fcac0480> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - locked <0x00000000fcac0480> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc098000 nid=0x27d7 in Object.wait() [0x00007f96c8af9000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - waiting on <0x00000000fcad0070> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - locked <0x00000000fcad0070> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc00e800 nid=0x27be waiting on condition [0x00007f96d3837000]
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   - parking to wait for  <0x00000000f7669c00> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.WaitingThread.await(WaitingThread.java:158)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:402)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:299)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:242)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:456)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:334)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:281)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestGet(RestStorageService.java:981)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:2150)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:2087)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObject(StorageService.java:1140)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObject(S3Service.java:2583)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObject(S3Service.java:84)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObject(StorageService.java:525)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at com.cloudera.org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObject(S3Service.java:1377)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:118)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy11.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:414)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1378)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.rename(DistCp.java:484)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.copy(DistCp.java:461)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:547)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:314)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc091800 nid=0x27d6 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc021800 nid=0x27bf runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc023800 nid=0x27c0 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc025800 nid=0x27c1 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc027000 nid=0x27c2 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc029000 nid=0x27c3 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc02b000 nid=0x27c4 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc02c800 nid=0x27c5 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc02e800 nid=0x27c6 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc030800 nid=0x27c7 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc032000 nid=0x27c8 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#10 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc034000 nid=0x27c9 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#11 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc036000 nid=0x27ca runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#12 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc037800 nid=0x27cb runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#13 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc039800 nid=0x27cc runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#14 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc03b800 nid=0x27cd runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#15 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc03d000 nid=0x27ce runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#16 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc03f000 nid=0x27cf runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#17 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc041000 nid=0x27d0 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#18 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc042800 nid=0x27d1 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#19 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc044800 nid=0x27d2 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#20 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc046800 nid=0x27d3 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#21 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc048000 nid=0x27d4 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "GC task thread#22 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc04a000 nid=0x27d5 runnable 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: "VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96cc0d1000 nid=0x27dd waiting on condition 
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: JNI global references: 1678
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2: Heap
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:  PSYoungGen      total 191168K, used 134794K [0x00000000f2ab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   eden space 163904K, 78% used [0x00000000f2ab0000,0x00000000fa91fef0,0x00000000fcac0000)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   from space 27264K, 19% used [0x00000000fcac0000,0x00000000fcff2af8,0x00000000fe560000)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   to   space 27264K, 0% used [0x00000000fe560000,0x00000000fe560000,0x0000000100000000)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:  PSOldGen        total 436928K, used 0K [0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000f2ab0000, 0x00000000f2ab0000)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   object space 436928K, 0% used [0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000f2ab0000)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:  PSPermGen       total 28160K, used 28023K [0x00000000d2e00000, 0x00000000d4980000, 0x00000000d8000000)
attempt_201312042223_7900_m_000003_2:   object space 28160K, 99% used [0x00000000d2e00000,0x00000000d495dd20,0x00000000d4980000)
```

I retried same dataset from another cluster w/ the prior version and I am having no issues.  Was something changed where distcp function now no longer properly closes http connection using jets3t?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.